# Index of elements in sublist in list python

Tags: python, list

given these lists:

```
list1 = [[A,A,B,C],[A,A,B,C]]
list2 = [[C],[A,C]]
```

I am trying to locate the index of each sublist 2 in each sublist 1:

```
result = [[3],[0,1,3]]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: What did you try? Please, show us the code to help you